# Graphics device not opening using Diagram package

Tags: r

I have a .Rmd that has rendered fine for the least few years, but has suddenly broken to what I believe is an issue with the graphics device. Here is the code where I think it is broken.

```
suppressMessages(library(diagram))

## open plot 
par(mar = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
openplotmat()
## define number of boxes at each level
elpos <- coordinates (c(3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1))
## generate matrix of from-to arrow coordinates
fromto <- matrix(ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE,
                 data = c(1, 6,
                          2, 4,
                          3, 7,
                          4, 5,
                          5, 6,
                          5, 7,
                          6, 8,
                          7, 9,
                          8, 10, 
                          9, 10,
                          10, 11,
                          11, 12))
nr <- nrow(fromto)
arrpos <- matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = nr)

# HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURES.
i = 1
arrpos[i, ] <- straightarrow(to = elpos[fromto[i, 2], ],
                                from = elpos[fromto[i, 1], ],
                                lwd = 1, arr.pos = 0.6, arr.length = 0.2)
```

This is literally the same code that has worked for years, but I am now getting "plot.new() has not yet been called" error. So I am wondering if something maybe changed with the "openplotmat()". I have the most recent version of the diagram package.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, turns out this is not a code issue or an issue with the diagram package, but has something to do with RStudio. Once I unchecked the “show output inline for all R Markdown Documents” box in global preferences, I had no issues. For some reason when that box is checked functions like plot.new() and openplotmat() don't seem to work as expected.